# Random sampling and over sampling

Tags: sampling, oversampling

I have binary $\{0,1\}$ classification data that I will use for statistical analysis. The data provider said that the data are randomly drawn from the population and at the same time he said samples with class $1$ is oversampled.

Here oversampling does NOT mean a copy of the minority class. Simply in the data, probability of class $1$ is higher than the population.

In this case, can I say that oversampling was done randomly? For instance, class $1$ is randomly sampled with higher than 0.5 probability and class $0$ is sampled with less than 0.5 probability?

I cannot really talk to the data provider. Above statement comes from the data description.

Comment: How exactly did the data provider define “random sampling”? By “oversampled” they mean that by chance one class is more frequent or something else? Hard to comment without understanding what that meant since the statements are contradictory.

Comment: @Tim yes "oversampled" means one class $1$ is more frequent than the other.

Comment: @Tim or is there anyway that sampling done is independent of features?

Comment: Sampling is done randomly within each class.